Should TypeScript downcompile named import attributes?
TypeScript 5.3 introduced support for import attributes. When building an ESM project, the compiler allows using named imports, but I don't know any javascript runtimes that support this. Should TypeScript be downcompiling or disallowing named imports from JSON imports?
index.ts
import {compilerOptions} from './tsconfig.json' with {type: 'json'};
console.log(compilerOptions);

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2023",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}

package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22",
    "typescript": "^5.5"
  }
}

Test building with Node.js 22.6.0 and TypeScript 5.5.4.
Compilation with npx tsc produces no warnings or errors and outputs index.js:
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json' with { type: 'json' };
console.log(compilerOptions);

Attempt to run in Node.js 22:
> node index.js          
(node:11064) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
file:///C:/Users/matt.mower/source/with-json-tsc/index.js:1
import { compilerOptions } from './tsconfig.json' with { type: 'json' };
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './tsconfig.json' does not provide an export named 'compilerOptions'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:171:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:254:5)
    at async onImport.tracePromise.__proto__ (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:482:26)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:117:5)

Node.js v22.6.0

Attempt to run in Chrome 127.0.6533.120 (<script async type="module" src="./index.js"></script>):
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './tsconfig.json' does not provide an export named 'compilerOptions' (at index.js:1:10)

If I replace the named import with the following, index.js runs fine in both Node.js 22 and Chrome 127:
import tsconfig from './tsconfig.json' with { type: 'json' };
console.log(tsconfig.compilerOptions);


I'm having a hard time getting a linkable reproduction of this. Do you have any way of demonstrating in codesandbox or stackblitz or some other web IDE?

Here's a repository with a minimal reproduction. You should be able to clone it and run GitHub codespaces. https://github.com/mdmower/with-json-tsc

I'm trying to look at this and I'm surprised there's no error on the named imports given that JSON modules don't support this anywhere. But I don't know if it really has much to do with import attributes. TS completely ignores import attributes, on purpose. I'd say if there is a bug or problem here it's that TS seems to allow named imports with --resolveJsonModule, with or without with {type:'json'}. But this is really outside my area of expertise so I'm not sure how to proceed.

(see prev comment) Closest I can find is this GitHub comment

Named imports work when transpiled to CommonJS. import { compilerOptions } from "./tsconfig.json"; becomes const tsconfig_json_1 = require("./tsconfig.json"); console.log(tsconfig_json_1.compilerOptions);
I suppose I need to heed the release notes where it says: The contents of these attributes are not checked by TypeScript since they’re host-specific, and are simply left alone so that browsers and runtimes can handle them (and possibly error).

Ah, yeah, from your GitHub comment link, I see they were at least aware of this limitation: "(and not having any named imports is unfortunately going to be a big change from current behavior, too)". Seems like it should be enforced.

Right, if you are using node modules it sure looks like named imports should be prohibited, especially given ms/TS#46434. Can't figure out why it's not flagged. Maybe someone more familiar with this could chime in or file a github issue? I think I'm going to disengage because I'm not even close to an expert on this module stuff. Good luck!

Created GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/59684

^ @MDMower The release notes are still accurate: the compiler won't check this (yet, at least).

^ Some runtimes support importing of parsed JSON data using the import attributes proposal, but the proposal only allows for binding the entire parsed value to the default export. One reason for this is that a JSON file can contain any serialized JSON value — any of the other types besides string-keyed objects, including primitive types (boolean, number, null, string) and array literals of other JSON values — and named imports don't make sense in those cases.

Microsoft fixed this issue in TypeScript 5.7 (not yet released). Named imports will not be allowed when importing JSON with import attributes.
Pull request: Validate JSON imports into ESM in --module nodenext
Snippet from description:

Errors on named imports of JSON-file imports in --module nodenext, since those don't work in Node.js.

